# $1-F$ is rapidly varying if and only if there exists $b_n$ such that $\frac{\max X_i}{b_n} \to 1$ in probability

Tags: probability, extreme-value, measure-theory

The following is a problem from Extreme Values, Regular Variation and Point Processes by Resnick.

We will say $1-F$ is rapidly varying as $x \to \infty$ if $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1-F(tx)}{1-F(t)} = 0$ for $x>1$ and the limit is equal to $\infty$ for $0<x<1$.

Let $X_n$ be i.i.d random variable with common distribution $F$. Let $M_n = \max_{i=1, \ldots, n} X_i$.

Then we want to prove that there exists constants $0<b_n$ with $b_n \to \infty$ such that $\frac{M_n}{b_n} \to 1$.

The converse, assuming $1-F$ is rapidly varying and setting $b_n = U^{-1}(n)$ where $U = \frac{1}{1-F}$ and the inverse refers to generalized inverse for monotone function, since in the previous section we have already proved that $\frac{U(b_n)}{n} \to 1$, is immediate.

But proving $\frac{M_n}{b_n} \to 1$ in probability implies $1-F$ is rapidly varying has been hard.

We know that $n(1-F(b_n x)) \to 0$ for $x>1$ and $n(1-F(b_n x)) \to \infty$ for $x<1$, but we get no information about convergence of $n(1-F(b_n))$, and it seems this can converges to any positive value.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can be explicit about $b_n.$ For instance, define $b^\prime_n=F^{-1}(1-2^{-n}).$ This is the median of the distribution of $M_n,$ whence $\Pr(M_n\le b^\prime_n)\ge 1/2$ and $\Pr(M_n\ge b^\prime_n)\ge 1/2.$ Thus, if $M_n/b^\prime_n$ doesn't converge to $1$ in probability, no such sequence $b_n$ can exist; and if such a sequence exists, you may use $(b_n^\prime)$ in its place without loss of generality.